# 'CityListViewSet' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, assertion, django-rest-viewsets

I am assuming by the error in the title, once more here for clarity

```
'CityListViewSet' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, 
or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.
```

that my serializer isn't connected to my view, which in my code it should be. I'm not really sure where the bug is in this one. I wonder if any of you have seen something similar?

Here is the code.

Router:

```
router.register(r'city-list', CityListViewSet, base_name='city-list')
```

view:

```
class CityListViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):                 
    queryset = Venue.objects.values('city').distinct()
    serializer = CitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
    ordering_fields = ('city',)
    ordering = ('city',)
```

serializer:

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields =('city',)
```

what is it that would be causing such an assertion error with the code seemly wired up correctly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The exception says it itself. You need a `serializer_class` attribute. You have `serializer`.

Comment: lol and I confirmed what you just said in the docs. OK your right my bad thank you

Comment: this brought a new issues which is `'ListSerializer' object is not callable` currently researching it

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure it's related? Because you're not using ListSerializer anywhere in your code example.

Comment: my `CityListViewSet` is inheriting from `viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet` I wonder if that might be the cause

Comment: Hmm. I just took a look at the DRF source and I don't see any reference to ListSerializer.

Comment: it is werid. Im going to see what I can find

Comment: For a noob like me, it means in your `CityListViewSet`, add  `serializer-class = CitySerializer`

Answer (score 4):

Add this code snippet to your `views.py` file

```py
class CityListViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):  # (viewsets.ModelViewSet) 
    serializer_class = CitySerializer
            
    queryset = City.objects.values('city').distinct()
    serializer = CitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
    ordering_fields = ('city',)
    ordering = ('city',)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
serializer = CitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

The above line should be replaced with

```
serializer_class = CitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

error says you define a serializer attribute, you need to correct with writing
serializer_class attribute in your code,

```
serializer_class = yourCreatedSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you used a different model name:

view:

```
class CityListViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):     #(viewsets.ModelViewSet)             
queryset = City.objects.values('city').distinct()
serializer = CitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
ordering_fields = ('city',)
ordering = ('city',)
```

import -> from .serializers import TaskSerializers,CitySerializer

serializer:

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
class Meta:
    model = City
    fields =('city',)
```

Answer (score 1):

i got this error when declared post method in view and trying to send post data without serialize, if you are doing the request from javascript i solved it using `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

you have to override the user just add

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser
```

and in createViewList

```py
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename this to

```
    serializer = CitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

This

```
    serializer_class = yourCreatedSerializer
```

Your job is done